# ffmpeg - missing avformat headers

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I follow the steps [here to compile FFmpeg.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)
And there is no problem. Its working well. But i did not understand something.
There are two folders under my home directory.
--ffmpeg_sources
--ffmpeg_build

insede of ffmpeg_sources/libavformat i have number of headers

```
aiff.h
apetag.h
argo_asf.h
asfcrypt.h
asf.h
ast.h
av1.h
avc.h
avformat.h
avi.h
avio.h
avio_internal.h
avlanguage.h
ogg.h
...
```

but ffmpeg_build/avformat has 3 header.

```
avformat.h
avio.h
version.h
```

btw this is my usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat

```
avformat.h
avio.h
version.h
```

Why aren't all headers in these other two files?
For ex: i want to use "ogg_read_packet" but when i try to `include <libavformat/oggdec.h>` i get `cannot open source file "libavformat/oggdec.h"C/C++(1696)` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building and using the library aren't the same things.

Have a look at [libavformat/oggdec.h](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/oggdec_8h.html) and [libavformat/oggdec.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/oggdec_8c.html). You should have realized, that there is no way to directly use the `ogg_read_packet` function.

1. there is no declaration in the header file
2. the function is declared static in the source file

If you want to encode/decode with a specific codec (here ogg), you have to find an encoder ([avcodec_find_encoder](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__encoding.html#ga9f820c481615c3a02d0407bac0bdbf25) or [avcodec_find_encoder_by_name](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__encoding.html#gaa614ffc38511c104bdff4a3afa086d37)) or a decoder ([avcodec_find_decoder](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga19a0ca553277f019dd5b0fec6e1f9dca) or [avcodec_find_decoder_by_name](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga776f2359007e8457799503068419e791)) and link it to a [AVCodecContext](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/structAVCodecContext.html) via [avcodec_open2](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__core.html#ga11f785a188d7d9df71621001465b0f1d).

Then for encoding use the 'encode' functions described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__encoding.html) and for decoding the 'decode' functions described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html).

For more info:

- [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/index.html)
- [FFmpeg Examples](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/examples.html)

In short, use the public Interface. Only 'God' knows the internals of FFmpeg.